# Symbolic link permissions don't change with chmod

Tags: permissions, symlink, chmod

I have access to a remote Linux machine where every time I create a symbolic link, it is created by default with the following permissions: `lrwxrwxrwx`

If I try to change the permissions of the symbolic link (i.e. not the path that it points to) using for example:

```
chmod g-w my_symbolic_link
```

`chmod` runs correctly (no error message is printed) but when I check the permissions again, they are still the same (`lrwxrwxrwx`).

I am waiting to hear from the machine administrator, but I was wondering if this is normal behavior, or if it is something specific to the box.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's normal behavior.  What happens can vary depending on the operating system (Solaris at least used to change the link permissions); but since a symlink isn't a normal file, the permissions don't actually get used for anything.  (File permissions are part of the file's inode, so the symlink can't affect them.)

Comment: I see, thanks. I just want to prevent anybody from deleting the symbolic link. From what I understand then I cannot change the permission of this link without the help the administrator, correct?

Comment: Not even with the administrator's help. File deletion depends on the permissions of the containing directory, not on those of the file. (`rm` specifically checks the file for read-only unless you pass `-f`, because one usually doesn't intend a read-only file to be deleted, but `unlink()` doesn't care. Try it from Perl or Python sometime.)